# Does the following sentence make grammatical sense?

Tags: grammar, sentence

I am writing and essay and I am not sure if the following sentence makes grammatical sense (especially the bold part):

"This shows that Victor thinks so little of himself that he must fill the **empty void where his freedom would lie had he been born wealthy with greater and greater accomplishments**. "

I always welcome feedback or suggestions.

EDIT: I am unsure if it is correct because it seems incorrect to add "had he been born wealthy" in the middle of that sentence. It gives me the impression that it can easily be misread to mean something other than what I want it to mean. Which is that there is an empty void in place of where his freedom would have been, had he been born wealthy.

Thank you.

Comment: This is Off Topic proofreading unless you specify *exactly* what aspect of the text you're unsure about - and ***why***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I added an edit to clarify.

Comment: If you’re just asking about grammar ... it’s grammatical.

Comment: Yes, that is all I wanted to know. Thank you Lawrence.

Comment: I'm not sure of the point of  describing the void as empty. Most voids of my acquaintance are as empty as they can get. Though you are welcome to your redundancy.

Comment: "Yes, that is all I wanted to know." Many people who ask questions here think that grammaticality is paramount. Yes, it's really important. But Professor Lawler once said of a sentence "Yes, it's grammatical – but that's the only good thing you can say about it." Chomsky contrived the totally grammatical sentence 'Colorless green ideas sleep furiously' to show that grammatical rubbish exists. And Orwell famously added a caveat 'Break any (other) rule in English rather than ending up with something sounding unnatural' (paraphrasing).

Comment: Your edit clarifies what you want to say, and the sentence is grammatical. However it suffers from attachment ambiguity. The pp _with greater and greater accomplishments_ is separated from _fill the empty void_ to which it needs to attach. You can remove the ambiguity by separating off _had he been born wealthy_ with commas. More about attachment ambiguity on Language Log: https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=17711

Comment: I'd set the phrase "where his freedom would lie" off in commas